# Angular errors does not show in debug google chrome

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, google-chrome-devtools

I am learning Angular recently. I have a newbie question that I did not find the answer yet after checking internet and trying to find it out myself.

I installed angular and basically made a new angular app. Then I also run the "ng serve".
I also changed the app.component.html under the source/app folder to be simple as :

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" [(ngModel)]="binding">
<p>{{binding}}</p>
```

I did not defined "binding" inside app.component.ts nor import FormsModule inside app.module.ts
Clearly, by saving the file I got error inside angular that is ran inside atom ( I use atom IDE).

But when I check the google chrome debug, I do not see any error. So if I type something in the input that should be replicated inside P tag, in the IDE I see the errors but not in google chrome debug section.
Anyone, knows why I could not see the error inside GC debug? I also did the same in Firefox and also I did not see errors from angular in debug mode. Is there any setting that need to be done inside angular that the errors from angular shown inside browser debug section?

Thanks

Comment: May I know your IDE error ?

Comment: Sure :

    1 <input type="text" name="" value="" [(ngModel)]="bindedValue">
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Comment: I also see there is not a consistency between the browser and angular. For example If I add "import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';" and "FormsModule" in the import section of app.module.ts the application runs correctly ( everything in the input will be replicated to the p tag) but now, I remove FormsModule and save the file, but the browser still replicate what is in the input field to p tag even if I refresh the browser. If I stop ng serve and re-run it sometimes I get "error Get in" in the browser too

Comment: Just curious.. what angular version are you on? Also.. this: <p name="binding"></p> - shouldn’t do anything..

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the code ( I miss typed it here) .  The last version ( just installed in yesterday)